# Submitting the form automatically once the file is uploaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a icon when clicked automatically open the file upload dialog box just like `<input type = "file">` does. My form doesn't have submit button. I want to submit the form when the user selects the file and presses open in the dialog box. I have written a jquery code. But it doesn't seem to work

Here is my form

```
<label for="avatar" id="avatar_label">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</label>  
<form id="change_pic_form" action="/nothing">
    <input type="file" name="avatar" id="avatar">
</form>
```

My jQuery doesn't seem to work

```
if ($('#avatar').get(0).files.length !== 0) {

    $('#change_pic_form').submit();
}
```

Comment: use on change event inside input type file and put your js code in that callback function

Answer (score 1):

You should use `onChange` event of file element.

```
document.getElementById('avatar').onchange = function() {
  if ($('#avatar').get(0).files.length !== 0) {
    $('#change_pic_form').submit();
  }
}
```

Comment: This is one of those situations where jQuery is so not needed.

Comment: @Mikey but the OP is clearly already using jQuery and might be using it for many other things other than this example of problem.